# Mahout Cookbook - Weird FileNotFoundException

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I'm following the mahout cookbook example. In one of them, I'm getting an exception:

```
mahout seqdirectory -i /home/hduser/cook/lastfm/current -o /home/hduser/cook/lastfm sequencefiles/
```

And then, I'm getting the following exception:

```
14/04/29 15:45:38 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--charset=[UTF-8], --chunkSize=[64], --endPhase=[2147483647], --fileFilterClass=[org.apache.mahout.text.PrefixAdditionFilter], --input=[/home/hduser/cook/lastfm/current], --keyPrefix=[], --method=[mapreduce], --output=[/home/hduser/cook/lastfm/sequencefiles/], --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp]}
14/04/29 15:45:38 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
14/04/29 15:45:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/04/29 15:45:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
14/04/29 15:45:38 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /home/hduser/cook/lastfm/current
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1102)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.runMapReduce(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:162)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.run(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.SequenceFilesFromDirectory.main(SequenceFilesFromDirectory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:152)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

The problem is that the folder exists, as shown here:

```
hduser@ACER-V3-571G:~/cook/lastfm/current$ ls
artists.txt  ArtistTags.dat  README.txt  tags.txt
```

Mahout 0.9 and Hadoop 2.2.0

jps shows me:

```
5435 ResourceManager
7257 Jps
5531 NodeManager
5104 DataNode
5262 SecondaryNameNode
5008 NameNode
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but i found the solution by myself.

Since the file isn't in the Hadoop Filesystem, I should run mahout as local.

```
export MAHOUT_LOCAL=TRUE
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since an "export" configures a system environment variable in unix, an similar command should do it in Windows. Try:

```
SET MAHOUT_LOCAL=TRUE
```